# What's the fastest way to strip certain html tags in a Python string?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'd like to strip all html / javascript except for:

```
<b></b>
<ul></ul>
<li></li>
<a></a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want a way that's fast or a way that's correct? A regex-based approach is unlikely to be correct and may open you up to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

You should use an HTML parser like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or even `htmllib`.

Also, `<a>` can contain `javascript:` `href`s and there are also the various `on`* attributes which are javascript. You probably want to strip all of those out. In general, a whitelist approach is best: only keep attributes (and attribute values) you know are safe.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with Laurence, there are occasions where a quick and dirty 99% approach gets the job done without creating other problems.

Here's an example that demonstrates a regex based approach --

```
import re

CLEANBODY_RE = re.compile(r'<(/?)(.+?)>', re.M)

def _repl(match):
    tag = match.group(2).split(' ')[0]
    if tag == 'p':
        return '<%sp>' % match.group(1)
    elif tag in ('a', 'br', 'ul', 'li', 'b', 'strong', 'em', 'i'):
        return match.group(0)
    return u''

def cleanbody(html):
    return CLEANBODY_RE.sub(_repl, html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the elements you want to keep with a place holder value, then regex out any remaining <.*>, finally replace the placeholders with the corresponding html elements.

Comment: I suggest using BBcode for the placeholders, which gives you the nice side-effect of support BBcode without any extra computation.